# Color Palettes from storyboard used programmatically

Tags: ios, colors

I am building an app and I have multiple colors that I want a background to be depending on a predetermined factor. In my story boar I have tested and chosen the colors I wanted to use and I have put them in a palette on the color picker. First question can I programmatically call on the colors of the palette.
if that doesn't work I have already gotten the RGB values for each of the colors but when I try to go do this:

```
UIColor *myBlue =[UIColor colorWithRed:(60/255) green:(97/255) blue:(255/255) alpha:1.000];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = myBlue;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = myBlue;
```

it gives me the same color as of I go

```
[UIColor blueColor]
```

the reason I am creating my own color is because I don't want the predetermined colors but they are not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

(This might be a zombie issue, but for anyone else curious)

This is actually a bug because you're performing integer division instead of floating point division. Dividing an `int` by an `int` throws away the remainder. You're code is functionally equivalent to:

```
UIColor *myBlue =[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1.000];
```

Which of course is pure blue. To fix, force floating point division by making one of the numbers a `float` type. For example, you could change that line to:

```
UIColor *myBlue =[UIColor colorWithRed:(60/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1.000];
```